# Analytics causes website to crash

Tags: themes, google-analytics, footer

Okay so the website I webmaster for http://www.detroitdungeon.com has been having some analytic issues as of lately. I have the google analytics plugin installed and it was working fine for quite sometime. All of a sudden the plugin caused IE users to crash after the page had loaded. So instead of using the plug in I decided to use the code given to me by google and I placed it in the footer of the website. Doing this caused the webpage to crash with all browsers.
after the code has been placed in the footer the source code reads

```
<b>Parse error</b>: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in <b>/home/content/36/5385336/html/detroitdungeon/wp-content/themes/delighted_black2/footer.php</b> on line <b>5</b>
```

Here is footer.php

```
<?php 

include('footer_content.php');$delight_mainfont = get_option('delight_mainfont');echo '<div id="footcopy"><span class="left"><a href="http://zenverse.net/delighted-black-wordpress-theme/">Delighted Black</a> designed by <a href="http://yourchristianspace.com">Christian Myspace</a> & <a href="http://www.digitaldesignzmedia.com">Designed By: Digital Designz Media Group</a></span><span class="right">In conjunction with <a href="http://pingler.com">Ping Services</a>   <span style="font-family:tahoma;">|</span>   <a href="http://frenchteacherjobs.com">French Teacher Jobs</a>   <span style="font-family:tahoma;">|</span>   <a href="http://mathsteacherjobs.com">Maths Teacher Jobs</a> </span>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div>

<!--/page-->

<script type="text/JavaScript">var TFN='';var TFA='';var TFI='0';var TFL='0';var tf_RetServer="rt.trafficfacts.com";var tf_SiteId="254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16";var tf_ScrServer=document.location.protocol+"//rt.trafficfacts.com/tf.php?k=254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16;c=s;v=5";document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/JavaScript" src="'+tf_ScrServer+'">%3C/script>'));</script><noscript><img src="http://rt.trafficfacts.com/ns.php?k=254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16" height="1" width="1" alt=""/></noscript>

</body></html>';

?>
```

I tried going with godaddy analytics and the same issue is happening. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: the single quotes `'` in the line beginning with `<script type="text/JavaScript...` seem to be breaking the echo string; try to replace them all with double quotes `"` - 
or rewrite footer.php without using `echo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 

include('footer_content.php');$delight_mainfont = get_option('delight_mainfont');echo '<div id="footcopy"><span class="left"><a href="http://zenverse.net/delighted-black-wordpress-theme/">Delighted Black</a> designed by <a href="http://yourchristianspace.com">Christian Myspace</a> & <a href="http://www.digitaldesignzmedia.com">Designed By: Digital Designz Media Group</a></span><span class="right">In conjunction with <a href="http://pingler.com">Ping Services</a>   <span style="font-family:tahoma;">|</span>   <a href="http://frenchteacherjobs.com">French Teacher Jobs</a>   <span style="font-family:tahoma;">|</span>   <a href="http://mathsteacherjobs.com">Maths Teacher Jobs</a></span>
<div class="clear"></div></div></div>
<!--/page-->
';?>
<script type="text/JavaScript">var TFN='';var TFA='';var TFI='0';var TFL='0';var tf_RetServer="rt.trafficfacts.com";var tf_SiteId="254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16";var tf_ScrServer=document.location.protocol+"//rt.trafficfacts.com/tf.php?k=254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16;c=s;v=5";document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/JavaScript" src="'+tf_ScrServer+'">%3C/script>'));</script><noscript><img src="http://rt.trafficfacts.com/ns.php?k=254g7d80916f3af3bbc0ac2542301cd153424f1b1aa7h16" height="1" width="1" alt=""/></noscript>
</body></html>
```

Comment: When using that code the same error applies but it moves to line 8.

Comment: replacing single to double also causes the same error.

Comment: try the updated code above.

Comment: fixed! Did you just remove the bottom opening and losing php tags?

Comment: i closed the php tag before the closing body tag `?>` closes php code and migrated your `</body></html>` to the very end. If this is your accepted solution please click the check box under my answer

Comment: I did. thank you very very much! As always, these forums offer much more support then the official wordpress forums.

Comment: Thanks.That they do i asked for a long time over there and went weeks and months and never got a reply came here with the same question and withing minutes got a reply.

Comment: Same thing here. I've been having this issue for a little over a week. Hopped on here and you resolved it within a half hour.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently with our website, so I did the
    following.

1. Went to our Control Panel and launched (clicked on hosting)
2. Clicked the arrow for the drop down menu on the Files & FTP tab
3. Clicked File Manager
4. Clicked on the domain name (do not click the file or + beside your domain name) left side of the directory
5. Clicked on the name wp-content
6. Clicked plugins
7. Clicked box beside google-analytics-for-wordpress
8. Then I clicked rename at the top to rename folder
9. Renamed folder to google-analytics-for-wordpress1 (just added 1 at the end).
10. Went back to my site www.henpublishing.com and hit refresh (My site worked)
11. Returned to the google-analytics-for-wordpress folder.
12. Clicked rename
13. Deleted the 1 at the end (google-analytics-for-wordpress without the 1 at the end)
14. Went back to my site www.henpublishing.com and it worked with google analytics intact
15. It may crash again, not sure, but it is working for now. Perhaps, Google or WordPress will fix the problem soon. Hope this helps.